Why does the flutter app not build APK despite no problem?
Everytime I try to build Flutter app, it shows this error
Execution failed for task ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:androidJdkImage'.
   > Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: C:\Users\free\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-34\core-for-system-modules.jar.
         > Error while executing process C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\jlink.exe with arguments {--module-path C:\Users\free\.gradle\caches\tra
nsforms-3\fb247f22548bfd545efa0cbc10d96775\transformed\output\temp\jmod --add-modules java.base --output C:\Users\free\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\fb247f22548bfd545efa0cbc10d96775\transformed\output\jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}

Expecting to run.
Tried using both Java 17 and 21.

This should help: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/156304#issuecomment-2397707812

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
